# How can http://schema.org be used in JSON-LD's @context, even though it's not a JSON-LD file?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

As far as I can see in the JSON-LD spec, [section 3.1 - The Context](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#the-context), `@context` can either be:

- an inline JSON object:

  ```
  {
    "@context": {
      "name": "http://schema.org/name"
    }
  }
  ```
- or a string representing **the URI of an external JSON-LD file** containing such a JSON object:

  ```
  {
    "@context": "https://json-ld.org/contexts/person.jsonld"
  }
  ```

However, when used with the schema.org vocabulary, `@context` is always used this way:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
}
```

Even though http://schema.org is *not* the URI of a JSON-LD document.

**What did I miss?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org uses [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) to provide the JSON-LD context file.

If you request `http://schema.org` while sending the request header that you accept/prefer `application/ld+json`, this is what happens:

1. [`http://schema.org`](http://schema.org) 301-redirects to `https://schema.org/`

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Content-Type: text/html
   Location: https://schema.org/
   ```
2. [`https://schema.org/`](https://schema.org) 302-redirects to `https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.jsonld`

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Location: https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.jsonld
   ```
3. [`https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.jsonld`](https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.jsonld) gets delivered

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Type: application/ld+json; charset=utf-8
   ```

---

You can test it yourself with [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/ld+json" http://schema.org
```

`-L` makes curl follow redirects
`-H` includes the following header (`Accept: application/ld+json`) in the request

Comment: It did not even cross my mind that content negotiation could be used in this context. This makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: My understanding is that as of writin jsonld instead relies on the HTTP Link header to retrieve jsonld contexts. You can verify it by running `curl -IL http://schema.org`. Check out https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-api/#loaddocumentcallback for the current algorithm.